# Output newline in text file through batch

Tags: batch-file, text, wmic

I am using a  batch file to get bios information in a text file.
syntax I am using:

```
wmic bios >> information.txt
```

the output to the above syntax is properly.
Next, I want to write a text at the end of the same file.

for this I am using

```
echo. >>information>>txt
echo. >>information.txt    
echo This is the report generated. >> information.txt
```

but the output in the end of text file is 桤摶桶摶摣ഠ洊扤桪摶癨癤癨捤⁤ഠ洊扤桪摶癨癤癨捤⁤਍摭橢癨桤摶桶摶摣ഠ洊扤桪摶癨癤癨捤⁤਍
plz help

Answer (score 1):

The default output from WMIC is a unicode without BOM stream, 2 bytes per character. But the default output from `echo` command depends on `cmd` start options. By default the output from cmd is 1 byte per character.

When you look at your generated file contents, the systems detects it is unicode and adapt the read/write routines to this, but when the echoed text is found, it is handled as unicode and each 2 characters are considered one unicode char.

If the resulting file needs to be unicode, then the `echo` commands need to be executed inside a `cmd` instance started with the `/u` switch to force output from `echo` to be unicode. You can run all the batch inside this cmd instance or make calls when needed

```
wmic bios > information.txt
cmd /q /u /c "echo additional line >> information.txt"
```

Also, if the final file needs to include the BOM, you can include it indicating to `wmic` to directly generate the file instead of redirecting the output

```
wmic /output:information.txt bios
```

If the file does not need to be unicode, you can filter the output from `wmic` (`find`, `findstr` or `more`) to convert it to a single byte characters stream so later single byte character `echo` commands are correctly included in the stream

```
(
    wmic bios
    echo(
    echo(additional line
)|find /v "" > information.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

WMIC outputs its information in unicode.
Try like this to convert it to ASCII:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a  in ('wmic bios') do ( 
    for /f "delims="  %%z in ("%%a") do (echo %%z)>>info.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As npocmaka already stated, `wmic`gives you Unicode.

Here is another way to get 'wmic` output in ASCII:

```
wmic bios|findstr "^">information.txt
echo additional line>>information.txt
```